# On a New PC I Have Not Loaded the Operating System Once, but Recovery Options Ask for an Admin Password

Tags: windows-10, passwords, user-accounts, administrator

I have a new computer, and I have not loaded the operating system once (Windows 10). Therefore, I have not created any accounts. However, when I select the System Recovery option from the boot menu, most of the Advanced Options require I enter the password of an administrator account.

When I click the reset password link, I get the message

> This list only shows administrator accounts that have previously signed in to this PC, and does not include standard user or domain accounts. You need to be signed in as an administrator to use some repair and restore tools. If you don't have a password for any of these accounts, you can restart to try signing in to Windows to manage your user accounts.

Why are these options asking for a password if I have not created any accounts?

This video illustrates what I am experiencing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEfmZGIepU4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows comes preloaded with an Administrator account. In a new computer, when we have not loaded the operating system et all, the Administrator account is active because the manufacturer expects we'll go through loading the OS, which requires an administrator account to install all of the components. When we create the first account, the Administrator account becomes inactive.

Since I loaded the System Recovery environment (WinRE) before loading the OS et all, I was presented the Administrator account.

I was able to access this account and the various utilities of the Recovery environment, by leaving the password blank.